# Setting a third-party plugin setting in sbt AutoPlugin

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, scalastyle

I have an AutoPlugin which aggregates several third-party plugins and customizes their settings for our company. For most of the plugins, this works just fine by putting them in the `projectSettings`:

```
override lazy val projectSettings = Seq( somePluginSetting := "whatever" )
```

I tried to do this for ScalaStyle as well:

```
import org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin.scalastyleConfigUrl

override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
  scalastyleConfigUrl := Some(url("http://git.repo/scalastyle-config.xml"))
)
```

This setting is never visible in projects using my plugin, instead sbt uses the plugin-provided default value:

```
> inspect scalastyleConfigUrl
[info] Setting: scala.Option[java.net.URL] = None
[info] Description:
[info]  Scalastyle configuration file as a URL
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/kaeser/Documents/workspace/ci-test-project/}root/*:scalastyleConfigUrl
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (org.scalastyle.sbt.ScalastylePlugin) Plugin.scala:101
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:scalastyleConfigUrl
[info]  {.}/*:scalastyleConfigUrl
[info]  */*:scalastyleConfigUrl
[info] Related:
[info]  test:scalastyleConfigUrl
```

When I put the setting into build.sbt directly, it works as expected.

I made a simple example sbt plugin that shows the problem: https://github.com/jastice/sbt-customsettings

What might the issue be?

Comment: Can you give a project which worked before and no longer works?

Comment: I'll try to create a minimal project showing the problem

Comment: updated with link to example project

Comment: Did this work with 0.5.0?

Comment: I haven't tried with 0.5.0, since that version didn't play well with some of our projects, but I can try it with the example project tomorrow.

Comment: Fun story... I was the guy who wrote the `scalastyleConfigUrl` change. Anyway we had a reason at our company that we couldn't actually use my changes until today... I found out that the plugin got refactored some since I made the change so not only is the README out of date but also I couldn't get the setting to work. I was at my wits' end and was searching github for people using my feature and I found your repo. Small world. I "fixed" the problem by using the `in Compile` scope for now.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is most likely caused by the order in which settings are applied. If your plugin and the plugin you are depending on are both autoplugins, the `requires` value determines the order in which project settings are included.

Scalastyle still uses the old plugin format. It also does not follow the best practices. It should not set `projectSettings` as that makes it difficult to disable it in multi project builds. And it also prevents you from easily extending it from your custom plugin. I am not sure if the order in which project settings are applied is defined, or is determined by the order in which the plugins are loaded.

The easiest fix would be to make Scalastyle an `AutoPlugin` and depend on it using the `requires` value. Otherwise it's probably quite tricky to find out what determines the order.

Comment: For my case, I could fix the problem by simply setting `scalastyleConfigUrl in Compile` -- this one isn't overwritten by ScalaStyle. However, the `in Test` version is, so it's not a complete solution. I will probably try making ScalaStyle a proper AutoPlugin and see how that works out.